# The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.ExpirementalFeature' threw an Exception

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to execute a PowerShell script with C# with the System.Management.Automation.Powershell object in a **kiosk environment**, but I am always getting an exception and I have found nothing about this on the internet.

Here is my Exception:

```
    The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.ExperimentalFeature' threw an exception.

Exception: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.ExperimentalFeature' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig..ctor()
   at System.Management.Automation.Configuration.PowerShellConfig..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExperimentalFeature..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at ExamX_Service.WindowsService.PowershellHandler.executeCommand(String command) in F:\Programmieren\ExamX_Service\ExamX_Service\PowershellHandler.cs:line 31
   at ExamX_Service.WindowsService.WindowsBackgroundService.RunRecoveryScript() in F:\Programmieren\ExamX_Service\ExamX_Service\WindowsBackgroundService.cs:line 111
   at ExamX_Service.WindowsService.WindowsBackgroundService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in F:\Programmieren\ExamX_Service\ExamX_Service\WindowsBackgroundService.cs:line 73
```

And my code for executing the PowerShell script is:

```
private static PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

    public static string executeCommand(string command)
    {
        string errorMsg = string.Empty;
        string output = string.Empty;
        powerShell.AddScript(command);
        powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String");
        PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new();
        powerShell.Streams.Error.DataAdded += (object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            errorMsg = ((PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)sender)[e.Index].ToString();
        };

        IAsyncResult result = powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

        powerShell.EndInvoke(result);

        StringBuilder sb = new();

        foreach (var outputitem in outputCollection)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(outputitem.BaseObject.ToString());
        }

        powerShell.Commands.Clear();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
        {
            return errorMsg;
        }

        return sb.ToString().Trim();



    }
```

Any help or knowledge sharing is much appreciated.

Comment: Which NuGet package are you using?

Comment: System.Management.Automation and Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
I have more but I am using these two for the PowerShell script

Comment: Try using `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` only.

Comment: @mklement0 Is it relevant that this is in a Kiosk Environment and is running as a Windows Background Service?

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but it's certainly an unusual scenario. It's conceivable that the session in which services run lacks features associated with regular, interactive user sessions that PowerShell relies on.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the quick reply :) Do you know a way to still do this? I tried your method with only the PowershellSDK but it still has the same error. I am using the exact same code in a WPF application and it works fine there. So I guess it has something to do with the Kiosk environment. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I would start by opening an issue at  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/ to get an expert to tell you whether your scenario is fundamentally supported or not. Make it clear that you're trying to use the SDK _from a Windows service_.